# List selection in Ringtone shows a blue color for selected item. What color code is that?

Tags: iphone, listview

Do anyone know the color code for that blue selected text, as it is in Ringtone list?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

textfield.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:53/255.0 green:80/255.0 blue:129/255.0 alpha:1.0];

happy coding...